# Text formatting in Datagrid cell

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am trying to format numbers in datagrid data cells, in order to make *'1000000.52'* appear like : *'1 000 000.52'* for instance.

I have tried to look for properties that enable such things, and can only find the *ContentStringFormat* property inside the *DataGridCell* class. Unfortunately, what I tried do not work :

```
<DataGrid  CanUserAddRows="False" Name="EGrid" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=ExportableGrid}">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="## ### ###.00"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

How could I achieve this ? Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that the right way to solve this is to convert your double to a String and than work on it in orther to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create a custom value converter:

```
    Imports System.Globalization

Public Class DecimalFormatConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function IValueConverter_Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim decimalVal As Decimal = Nothing

        If value IsNot Nothing AndAlso parameter IsNot Nothing AndAlso Decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), decimalVal) Then
            Return decimalVal.ToString(parameter.ToString())
        End If

        Return value
    End Function

    Public Function IValueConverter_ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function

End Class
```

To use it in xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp6VB"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:DecimalFormatConverter x:Key="DecimalFormatConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DataGrid  CanUserAddRows="False" x:Name="EGrid" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Nums}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Number">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DecimalFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='## ### ###.00'}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: There I made a vb.net version.

Comment: First, thank you for your input. It seems to be the way to go. However, I cannot define each column manually in my case, since they may change (data is loaded from a request which changes along events at runtime).
I am trying to solve it with another property that is accessible from the DataGrid itself, but have trouble finding it.

Comment: I corrected it programmatically, since I realized you need the instance of a column to format its cells templates. An event handler connected to the _AutoGeneratingColumn_ event made this possible for every dynamically generated column.
You led me on the way, then I shall accept your answer. Thanks !

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to string, split it and add spaces where needed.

I hardcoded your problem.
If you want the snippet to work with different number, I suggest you to use the same logic and create a `Select/Case` on the lenght of the number.

This is the code to solve your problem:

```
    Dim number As Double = 1000000.52
    Dim str() As String = Convert.ToString(number).Split(",")
    str(0) = "" & _
        str(0).Substring(0, 1) & _
        " " & str(0).Substring(1, 3) & _
        " " & str(0).Substring(4, 3) & _
        "." & str(1)
```

Comment: Please if my answer statisfies you I will be glad if you'll [accpet it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: did you run this code? It throws an index out of range error.

Comment: I don't see a comma in number so the the split function returns a single element array. str(1) will cause an error.

Comment: No, I'm sorry but 1000000.52 is saved into the double var as `1000000,52`

Comment: Thank you for your input, but detecting number data, converting it and then formatting it seems to be a very heavy treatment in a DataGrid where there can be thousands of rows and dozens of columns.